# Zypper: Check last "zypper up" command time

Tags: date, sles, zypper

There is a script that checks whether packages up-to-date or not via a `zypper up`.

In this situation, team "A" creates the servers: they do `zypper up`, ok. 
Another team validates the servers: they check that `zypper up` doesn't show anything.

The problem: it may take one week or a full month until the validation team validates the servers, so when they issue a `zypper up`, they could see that, hey, it is not up-to-date!

We would need a solution that only checks that was it up-to-date when team "A" created the servers.

Are there any `zypper up` commands that only lists updates that were present 30 days before?

So far, I haven't seen this feature in: https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/index.html?page=/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_zypper.html or maybe just missing it out :\

OR at least a command that says/checks: "all the packages were upgraded in less than a month ago".

Comment: Would it be unacceptable for team "A" to run something like `typescript team-A-build.log; date; zypper up; exit` ?

Comment: Is the relevant information in `/var/log/zypper.log`?

Answer (score 0):

`zypper update` doesn't have any mechanism to show updates for a past date.
The validation should be based on a log captured during the update.
You can use `tee` or `typescript` or `STDIO` redirection to capture the log.